# Unable to connect to Server 2008 R2 physically or through LogMeIn

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, avg

We have several Windows Server 2008 R2 servers across different companies we provide remote support for. Each server is installed with LogMeIn Central.

When we try to login remotely (LogMeIn) to any of these servers we get stuck on "Verify Identity" step and then it disconnects our session.
We tried Remote Desktop connection and we connect but we can only see a black screen and nothing else! Can't ALT+CTRL+DEL or so...

I've had a technician on site and he physically connected a monitor/keyboard to server and there was no output on the screen! Additionally the keyboard was not responding!

Server roles (DHCP, SQL, AD, etc) appear to be working normally.. we just cannot login!

Anybody out there experience the same thing. All servers are on different locations so it's unlikely that it is a virus. The only thing these servers are sharing is the choice of antivirus software: AVG Business Edition (2012, 2013, 2015, etc...) and remote management (LogMeIn Central).

When we power cycle the server it works fine for a while and then the same issue re-appears. Event Log doesn't seem to point to anything obvious.

I suspect AVG Business Edtiion software to be responsible but it's more of a gut feeling rather than decision based on facts.

Anyone come across this before? Any hints? Thanks,

Comment: update:
We have decided to remove AVG Business Edition from 2008 servers for now. We, used AVG Removal Tool - it does work pretty well, but it restart server 2-3 times during removal procedure so be warned. 

So far, all affected servers seem to working as they should. Ah, we removed AVG Business Edition but we kept AVG Server Admin.. at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

Saw the same issue on 4 servers today, all running AVG Business Edition. All had several events related to AVG update logged just before hangup, both in System and Application logs. Could not gain access through console. 
After reboot, AVG windows says "UPDATE FAILED" but then manual update seemed to work and problem did not occur. Was at version 3495 before manual update to version 3520. Don't know if there was a buggy version released in between.

Look for Events 10010, 1025, 10005, and 1040 in System Event Log.

I also saw [this post](http://forums.overclockers.co.uk/showthread.php?p=28254408) pointing to AVG when searching web for similar issues

Comment: This morning we had 8 servers with the exactly the same issue. Users cannot connect to server. When accessing the monitor its just black and no response from keyboard. Once Server reboot is initated then all is working fine. As a precaution we are removing completely AVG Business Edition (Using AVG Removal Tool) and will investigate later on what's and why happened. It's nightmare... I hope AVG will man up and finally says what's actually going on. It does seem to only affect Server 2008 R2 at the moment.